# Jquery - Using top.location.pathname for multiple paths?

Tags: jquery, html, web

I'm trying to have a jquery function run if the url is on a couple distinct paths, particularly the index and the root. Right now, I have

```
"if (top.location.pathname === '/','index.html')
{ 
function happens
}
```

It works if I have only one pathname at the top but I don't know the syntax for having two. I'm also likely going to do something with the opposite, like:

```
"if (!top.location.pathname === '/','index.html')
{ 
function happens
}
```

Couldn't find anywhere online that explained this! I'm mostly self taught so if this is simple to do go easy on me, lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally sure about your syntax, having `'/'` and `'index.html'` separated by a comma seems unnecessary, you can just have `'/index.html'`.

On to the actual problem, this is a good time to use the logical *OR* operator, in Javascript it is typically used as `||`.

So as a simple example:

```
if (true || false) // happens, because one is true
if (false || false) // doesn't happen, nothing is true
if (false || false || false || false || true) // happens, because one is true
```

In your case, I imagine it would be:

```
if (top.location.pathname === '/index.html' || top.location.pathname === '/about.html')
```

I just used `about.html` as an example, you get the point. The condition will execute if at least one of those statements is true.

---

Addressing your second point, `(!top.location.pathname === '/','index.html')` will not work as expected.

Why?

Because the `!` negates the value of the variable it's attached to. In this case, you're saying `!top.location.pathname`, which is saying "take pathname, and negate it, and compare that to `/index.html`. In this case that means the condition will be along the lines of `false === '/index.html'`.

You're better off negating the operator itself: `(!top.location.pathname !== '/index.html')`.

And if you want to ensure that the pathname is not ANY of your or options, you can use the logical AND (&&) operator.

```
// only matches if the pathname is neither index.html or about.html
if (top.location.pathname !== '/index.html' && top.location.pathname !== '/about.html')
```